# Is it possible to refresh a customer level dataset daily to give churn predictions using BigqueryML

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to refresh a customer level dateset daily to give churn predictions using Bigquery ML

Answer (score 0):

You can run a [scheduled query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) to run CREATE MODEL periodically. The model is persisted in BigQuery storage when CREATE MODEL is executed.

For immediate updates, automating the pipeline workflow with either [Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer) or [AirFlow](https://airflow.apache.org/) is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

The word "*refresh*" here may have ambiguous meaning, and the word "*dataset*" probably refers to a BigQuery Table.
Your question as I understand it is ***whether you can create an up-to-date table with users and a churn score that was calculated using BigQuery ML***.

The answer is yes, after you train a model using BQML you can run scheduled queries to give you predictions. Please keep in mind:

- **Updating** data in a BigQuery table is *highly unrecommended*. Instead consider appending the results to a table with a timestamp that identifies the predictions (for each day let's say). Then create a view that shows only the most recent predictions.
- You may need to run a chain of queries for example: Create a training dataset with features, run predictions and save the results. For this you may want to use [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows).

Answer (score 0):

Solution to achieve your required solution is to create ML BQ model and store output at runtime. Then Use predicted output to perform any action of Bigquery tables.

You can execute Dataflow or simple python code to achieve required data archrivals.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import datetime
from google.cloud import bigquery


stream_query = """delete from `ikea-itsd-ml.test123.YOUR_NEW_TABLE4`  WHERE 1=1"""

stream_client = bigquery.Client()

stream_Q = stream_client.query(stream_query)
stream_data_df = stream_Q.to_dataframe()
```